# How change layout_height dynamically of ListView

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm using **Xamarin Studio** for **Android Apps**.

I want to change **android:layout_height** dynamically in **ListView**.

Actually, I'm using listview many places, But there it's height increasing automatically no need to set any value.

Just using this: **android:layout_height="wrap_content"**

But this list view use in

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">
          <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/llPRDeptHead"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:stretchColumns="1">
                <!-- Item Detail Table -->
                <TableRow>
                <TableRow>
                    <ListView
                        android:layout_span="6"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:dividerHeight="2px"
                        android:id="@+id/lvPRDeptHeadApproval" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: listview not working properly when use parent as scrollview...

Comment: Yes, it's not working properly. But I need scrollview. If use **android:layout_height="500dp"** then working fine. But I want to set dynamic from Activity class. Becoz it's depend on number of records and I'm getting ds from WCF.